# apply pinch and zoom to every page android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

Hi guys i have a medical application for android that will be used by the elderly. The problem is when they use the application they struggle to see the print. So i am looking to apply the pinch and zoom technique to the whole app so each page viewed can be zoomed in to make the font clearer. Can anybody point me in the right direction. I have looked at pinch and zoom examples and even downloaded some but they focus on images specifically. where as i want the content on every page to still function the way they do. i.e buttons etc. But i want every page to allow its users to zoom in.

Comment: There is nothing built into Android for this. Elderly users of Android 4.0+ devices should set their font scale to "Huge" in Settings, and then all of your `sp` dimensions will scale along with that font scale.

Answer (score 0):

This whole "Pinch and Zoom" thing is not really that usable as it requires a very high API to be used I think you should scrap it and try using the `SeekBar` that is connected to the size of the text it's a lot easier and it's something I have managed to implement quite easily in my apps from a very low API level. You can check this image of a snapshot of my App.

https://lh4.ggpht.com/9LDEkOV-QotFPHEa9SDpIHZ1OtgMgSDFdcrTsR1DZuBjpwonlAmREhhJQc3znVQ_LEo

If you want some code for this I may post it if you want

Comment: thanks but i think changing the size in the settings menu for the text worked perfectly.